# Writing unit test for SendMail function using SMTP

Tags: java, junit, smtp, mockito, jakarta-mail

i want to test SendMail function in my code.How can I mock session,properties,MimeMessage ?

I am using SMTP to send mail.

```
 JsonObject sendMail()
    {
       Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
                        }
                    });
            try {
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
                message.setSubject("xyz");
                message.setText("sjs");
                Transport.send(message);
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                String response = new String("{\"status\":\"failed\"}");
                return response;
            }
            String response = new String("{\"status\":\"sent successfully\"}");
            return response;
    }
```

Comment: what's wrong mocking `sendMail()` instead of `session`,`properties`, and `MimeMessage` and also please add cod what you tried

Comment: If I were to test this method, I would be more concerned about mocking the `Transport.send(message)`. Since mockito cant mock static methods it would require a bit of refactoring. Not sure what you are trying to accopmplish by mocking session, properties and MimeMessage.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not that simple, as you use static methods of the classes Session and Transport. By using static methods it is not possible to inject different mock objects, as mocks require an instance.

There is of course one solution, but it is really the last resort: use PowerMock(ito). It gives you the ability to mock static methods. But there are a few issues with PowerMock: it does not support JUnit5, it does not support Java 11 and the tests aren't measured by SonarQube. Also: the fact you need PowerMock actually tells you you need to rewrite your code so it will be testable.

Testable code uses a dependency injection framework (like Spring for instance) to dynamically insert the right object in the class. The cool thing of this feature is that you can inject Mock objects while testing the class.